# Can you completely steal credit card with MITM?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to understand how hackers get credit card information and use it online. If I had conducted an MITM attack on a store that accepts credit card, can I use the credit card information to buy things online?

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods of attack that are used for gathering CC, including skimming from fake ATM interfaces, Fake Card readers, Key Loggers on Computers, and compromised databases with poorly security practices.

MITM attacks are generally not as profitable because Merchants are forced to have common security processes in place to meet certain standards. In the US, the common one cited is PCI.

PCI covers not only the security for a merchant (PCI DSS), but also the components used such as readers and software (PA DSS).

Targeting a users prior to entering their information into the system is easier.

Comment: [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) applies worldwide, not just US

Comment: The question is about if the card info is useful after you get it, not if it is possible to get card info in a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are MITM and you can read the communication in clear text, YES.

The chances are that you will get the credit card number the owner name the expire date and the CVV.

That is what normally is provided to any shopper to validate the credit card.

The only thing between you and the successful buying of goods are the anti fraud team of the bank / store.

Credit card owners are usually profiled and abnormal behavior is easily detected.

Assuming that you use it wisely you might have a relative success for small amounts.
From a criminal perspective it is not worth it.
The risk of detection increases exponential when the criminal needs to repeat the process with multiple cards.

In USA because they still use magnetic stripe the information can be used to generate fake cards that might also be used in shopping. 
Also big risk for Small return and the criminal will have to risk his presence.

Answer (score 0):

This would be rather difficult. I don't know where you live, but in Europe, CNP transactions (i.e. online) use the credit card number, issue date/issue number, expiry date and the verification code (printed on reverse). Several providers also have a password check.

But for over the counter purchases, only the card number and the authentication code (gated by the PIN) is exchanged. i.e. your MITM attack will not capture the details required for online (or phone) payments.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the store, protection mechanisms used in store, online payment provider and credit card provider, understanding the SSL by the user in case he see a certificate cannot be verified message. It is possible in case of very bad implementation of the store payment processor. For credit card you need to attack user, not the store.

Answer (score 0):

Common sense rules, you don't need any sophisticated technology when the physical card is in place. The worst part of the credit card is the online purchase authentication, one just need to snap photo for both side of the credit card to gather all information.  A hacker can simply place a disguise camera to capture the image.

While getting caught to after conducting the fraud is another story. ;-)